# Hibernate JoinTable error: Unable to find column with logical name

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, psql

I am trying to do a Unidirectional ManyToOne association via a JoinTable in hibernate, but I keep getting the following error:

```
A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Unable to find column with logical name: name in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(users) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

I have 3 models `House`, `User`, `UserHouseMap`. I want to be able to access a users house through the `UserHouseMap`. Here is the mapping on the `User`

For other reasons, I need to map a `User` to `UserHouseMap` via a column that is not a primary key

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Expose
public Long id;

@Expose
@Required
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name = "user_house_map",
        joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(table="users", name="user_name", referencedColumnName="name")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(table="houses", name="house_name", referencedColumnName="house_name")})
public House house;
```

Here are the DB schemas for all 3 models

**Users**

```
                               Table "public.users"
        Column         |            Type             |          Modifiers          
-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------
 name                  | character varying(255)      |
 id                    | integer                     | not null 
Indexes:
    "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "housing_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES user_house_map(user_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**Houses**

```
                Table "public.houses"
    Column     |          Type          | Modifiers 
---------------+------------------------+-----------
 house_name    | character varying(255) | not null
 address       | text                   | 
 city          | text                   | 
 state         | text                   | 
 zip           | integer                | 
 zip_ext       | integer                | 
 phone         | text                   | 
Indexes:
    "house_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (house_name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "user_house_map" CONSTRAINT "house_map_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (house_name) REFERENCES house(house_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**UserHouseMap**

```
         Table "public.user_house_map"
   Column    |          Type          | Modifiers 
-------------+------------------------+-----------
 user_name   | character varying(255) | not null
 house_name  | character varying(255) | not null
Indexes:
    "user_house_map_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_name)
    "user_house_map_house_key" btree (house_name)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "user_house_map_house_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (house_name) REFERENCES houses(house_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "users" CONSTRAINT "housing_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES user_house_map(user_name) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: I think that is because you defined your user pkey as id and you are trying to join it with user_name therefore the error `bigint = character varying` try to remove the annotation @Id from the id field and see what happens

Comment: @JorgeCampos you were correct, so I changed the mapping to use referenceColumn. Check out my updated error

Answer (score 0):

Remove `table="users"` and `table="houses"` from the `JoinColumn` annotations.

This attribute should not contain the target table of the foreign key. It's only used when an entity is mapped to two tables, in order to tell which table the join column is in.

Also, your table definitions are quite strange:

- the join table should have two foreign keys: one referencing the PK of the users table, and one referencing the PK of the house table. Why do you reference the name of a user rather than its ID?
- the foreign key constraint on users.name doesn't make sense.